# How to get a custom menu in PWA (desktop)

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I want a custom menu on my PWA/TWA app. An example of this is [discord](https://discordapp.com). I want to remove the menu and add one myself.

[discord menu on G drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XVWBt7LDWEw_SXXxIM3Q47KKkjmj1zms/view?usp=sharing)

I've tried to use `display: fullscreen` in my manifest but it doesn't work.

**Update**

I realized I didn't explain it was a **desktop PWA** I meant. I search a lot but no results. Does anyone know if there's a way to install a PWA without the app tile menu?

Comment: What do you mean by menu? PWA doesn't have any menu out of the box. You should implement one yourself if you want to have it

Comment: [Here's google chromes default menu](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k2CuqpVQE8Z-4STkzBnTVkm5_DEmcer4)

Comment: It looks like PWA on desktop. Am I right? I only worked with mobile PWA and probably wouldn't be much help here. But as a quickfix you may try to add `div` with `position: absolute` to overlap that element.

Comment: Thanks, Arseniy-II
I'll try that anyway, but I think I first need to remove the default menu first. I don't think that the default menu is an added element because, when I look at the dev tools it collapses on the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the web manifest you can define different values within the `display` property. In your case, if you do not want to display the phone or minimal navigation elements (eg. back button), you were right in choosing `fullscreen`, however this still displays the title bar.

However if you want a custom header menu, you need to implement it by yourself. There are only limited possibilities to customise the title bar.

I wrote an [article about A2HS](https://dev.to/paco_ita/install-a-pwa-on-the-user-s-device-step-2-27pa), showing the different display modes, if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

PWA has its own App Shell which is precached assets that act as a menu.

You need to develop your menu specific UI [html, css] which can be positioned at top as shown in the example.

Comment: Shown in which example?

Comment: Thanks for the example Rohan. I made a update of my question because I forgot to say it was desktop PWA I meant.

Comment: The same code base works for Desktop as well, I have tested in Mac & Windows